# REdis Configuration file does not increase the databases

Tags: redis

In REdis, changing the Databases Number parameter the number of databases should be increased.

I have changed accordingly in the conf file. Restarted the database and tried to select the database as 16.

[redis.conf updated file with number 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7NXQ.png)

I get an error "(error) ERR invalid DB index"

I want to understand what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are using this conf file? `./redis-server /path/to/redis.conf`

Comment: I am in Redis folder which contains the Redis-server and Redis-cli . When I execute the command: C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server I get theis warning : Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by increasing the number of databases.  Using multiple databases in production is a deprecated pattern.

Comment: I am working on a school project, creating a new database is one of the points to include. That seemed so simple when reading the documentation but It just does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

Run the `info` ([ref here](https://redis.io/commands/info)) command or `info server` from the `redis-cli` tool and you will get the path to the loaded config file:

```
# Server
redis_version:999.999.999
redis_git_sha1:e09e31b1
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:f05c0e7d7d91e005
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.8.0-1-amd64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:6.2.0
process_id:14707
run_id:d3c34282582bad21e0af36ae2a214efa9dd52cea
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:3187359
uptime_in_days:36
hz:10
lru_clock:16298506
executable:/usr/local/bin/redis-server
config_file:
```